# Eclipse cannot find dependencies of a plugin built with Maven Tycho

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, tycho

I am using Maven Tycho to compile my projects which are structured like this :

```
- plugin1
 - plugin2 (depends on plugin1)
 - plugin3 (depends on plugin1 & 2)
 - plugin4 (depends on plugin1)
 - plugin5 (depends on plugin1 & 4)
 - plugin6 (depends on all previous plugins)
 - plugin7 (depends on all previous plugins)
{all these plugins are compiled as eclipse-plugin}
 - feature1 (contains all previous plugins) {eclipse-feature}
 - updatesite1 {eclipse-repository}
 - generalproject (contains only the parent pom)
```

I compile this via Eclipse (maven install), everything works and i can access my local repository, and install my feature in the same Eclipse (through "Install new software").

The problem is when i try to install my feature to another instance of Eclipse, which refuse to install it with the error :

```
(Missing requirement: Acceleo Texts Module IDE Plug-in 1.0.0.201612161812 (myproject.acceleo.ui 1.0.0.201612161812) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ocl 0.0.0' but it could not be found)
```

I know that this is a non satisfied requirement problem, but in Eclipse i checked "Contact all update sites during install to find required software", and my pom declares repositories containing all requirements, here is my parent pom :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myproject.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject.general</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

   <properties>
  <tycho.version>0.23.0</tycho.version>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

  <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>Mars</id>
   <layout>p2</layout>
   <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/</url>
  </repository>

   <repository>
  <id>Sirius</id>
   <layout>p2</layout>
   <url>http://download.eclipse.org/sirius/updates/releases/4.1.2/mars/</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

 <build>
  <plugins>

     <plugin>
    <!-- enable tycho build extension -->
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
   </plugin>

   <plugin>
    <!-- enable tycho build extension -->
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
     <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
    <configuration>
    <environments>
    <environment>
      <os>linux</os>
      <ws>gtk</ws>
      <arch>i386</arch>
    </environment>
     <environment>
          <os>linux</os>
          <ws>gtk</ws>
          <arch>x86_64</arch>
        </environment>
       <environment>
          <os>win32</os>
          <ws>win32</ws>
          <arch>x86</arch>
        </environment>
        <environment>
          <os>win32</os>
          <ws>win32</ws>
          <arch>x86_64</arch>
        </environment>
        <environment>
          <os>macosx</os>
          <ws>cocoa</ws>
          <arch>x86_64</arch>
        </environment>
     </environments>
   </configuration>
   </plugin>

  </plugins>
 </build>

 <modules>
  <module>../myproject</module>
  <module>../myproject.acceleo</module>
  <module>../myproject.acceleo.ui</module>
  <module>../myproject.design</module>
  <module>../myproject.edit</module>
  <module>../myproject.editor</module>
  <module>../myproject.plugin</module>
  <module>../myproject.project</module>
  <module>../myproject.site</module>
 </modules>
</project>
```

I cannot figure how to resolve this ? did i omit something in my procedure ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I fell for the same thing. Tycho does not include all dependencies, even though that's normal and desired maven behaviour. As maven does not "see" tycho (so manifest-derived) dependencies, they are not included.

You can override this behaviour by setting  to true:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
 <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>${tycho-version}</version>
 <configuration>
    <includeAllDependencies>true</includeAllDependencies>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Eclipse installation where you want to install your feature does not have an update site configured that contains org.eclipse.ocl. This has nothing to do with your Maven build, as long as you didn't configure your feature to also contain the required bundles, which could also be done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and since i cannot force to user to configure his Eclipse, i should follow your second suggestion, which i thought i already did by adding required repositories to my pom file, no ?

Comment: No, in your feature you could add the required plugins also to the Included Plug-ins, which actually means that your feature also contains the required bundles. By only specifying the dependency you only tell that it is required, not included.

Comment: i see, but even when i add "org.eclipse.ocl" to the included plugins in my feature, the same error persists  : myproject.acceleo.ui 1.0.0.201612161812) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ocl 0.0.0' but it could not be found.

N.B : myproject.acceleo.ui  is the third plugin of my feature.

Comment: maybe org.eclipse.ocl has also dependencies that can not be resolved and that error is a follow up?

Comment: maybe, i don't fully understand the problem. I also added repositories to "sites to visit" in feature information tab, but this doesn't change anything.